# Default selected value for <form:radiobutton /> using spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In spring mvc I am taking the dynamic hobbies values from the database. 
I have to select any one the hobby.

I can take the value and rendering in HTML

```
Map<String, List<?>> map = new HashMap<String, List<?>>();
map.put("hobbiesList", hobbiesList);
return new ModelAndView("register", "map", map);
in html
<form:radiobuttons path="hobby"
items="${map.hobbiesList}" />
```

If I do that , it is showing the list, but my requirement is when loading these hobbies, the default value has to be in selected mode.

Answer (score 0):

So there's two things, one is the list of available options (hobbiesList) and one is the hobby that is to be selected.

You are setting the `path` to `hobby`, but I don't see where there comes from.

You would normally pass in an Entity or Form Backing Object as the structure representing the information filled in with the form. Can you update your code to show that?

In your controller's get handler, create a form object, and set it's hobby to something:

```
@RequestMethod
ModelAndView getForm() {
  ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
  MyForm myForm = new MyForm();

  myForm.hobby = "some hobby";

  mav.addObject("map", myForm);

  //add your hobbiesList too here, or in a @ModelAttribute method

  mav.setViewName("register");
  return mav;
}
```